# In GooglePlay console : 'Alert – One of your apps needs attention' => How to know which app is concerned?

Tags: google-play

I am having this error[image]

I don't know which app is concerned. How to figure out what is the problem and what app ? I went on each dashboard, and there is no details or warning.

Comment: Well, based on the message an app being "removed" ... there is one status listed as "Removed" (the one with the red minus icon)... is that not the one?

Comment: Nope, I removed it manually few weeks ago. However it has the same name as the one I published (first line)

Comment: Can you check the store to see what is missing?  If you only have a few apps, I would think that would be obvious to find what is missing by simple process of cancellation.

Comment: It seems that even when you remove your app, Google Play will continue complaining about it. Since you can't actually delete an app, you'll need to fix the problem for the message to go away.

Comment: But I can't find out what app has a problem

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It's because I forgot to update/add privacy policy to the my app in console.

I got the same red mark which is in your second row.

Please check any old app without privacy policy is in your console. If yes, then because of the same app you get the alert.